# How to remove leading zero's in between characters of a string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have dates like this in string that need leading zero's removed.

Here is what I need:

Remove leading zero's in between `[-` and `:`

Below are some of the examples and expected results

1. 20200831000000.000[-05:EST] -> 20200831000000.000[-5:EST]
2. 20200831000000.000[-08:30:EST] -> 20200831000000.000[-8:30:EST]
3. 20200831000000.000[-10:EST] -> 20200831000000.000[-10:EST]

I can't figure this out as I'm new to regular expressions. I have tried the below but not working

```
"0+(?!$)"
```

Comment: @Jonathan updated question, added examples with more description.

Answer (score 1):

this will work like you went :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arr[] = {"20200831000000.000[-05:EST]","20200831000000.000[-08:30:EST]","20200831000000.000[-10:EST]"};
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length ; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i].replaceAll("(?<=\\[-?)(0*)(?=.*\\])", "");
    }
    for(String s : arr){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

output :

```
20200831000000.000[-5:EST]
20200831000000.000[-8:30:EST]
20200831000000.000[-10:EST]
```